# How do I add an active class for a views row?

Tags: views, theming, nodes

I have a view block that lists different nodes. If I am viewing the block on any of those pages I'd like to add an .active class (or at least some kind of identifier) to highlight it with CSS as a form of active trail.

I have no clue on how to do this though, and I can't really find any useful documentation for this either.

Should I do this in a template, within views UI?
If i could get the current node ID `views-view-fields--products--block-1.html.twig` I could compare it to the individual row IDs i guess?

[I've seen this patch](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2652000), but I'd rather get a better understanding how I am supposed to achieve this myself than just adding a random patch.

Comment: Go for JS and compare the link of the item with the current URL.

Comment: Also means: I have no idea what .active should be referring to here. Clicked item? Current URL? Selected? Could be just CSS.

Comment: Drupal Menus do this automatically, I expected it might work in Views? If not, I'd add a Contextual ID filter but set it to show all results, just to get a token working about which node you're visiting and passing it to Views. Then you can use that token in the CSS class option under Style in Field settings. I haven't tried it, I'm just suggesting what you might try.